# Store boolean value in xml document and read using PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do you store boolean values in an XML document such that you can read them using PHP's SimpleXML class?

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<status>
<investigating></investigating>
<log>
sample log
</log>
</status>
```

And the following php script to read it:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $statusXml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
        if ($statusXml) {
            $investigating = (bool)($statusXml->investigating);
            echo $investigating;
        }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open ' . $filename .'.');
}
```

No matter what I put in the  tag, it always gets read as true. I've tried "0", empty string, "false", and a bunch of other ideas but nothing has worked. I thought empty string should would because of what I found in this doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question should have left a comment explaining his reasons. Otherwise, it isn't very constructive. (And I think it's a pretty good question anyway.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that:

1. XML data is always a string
2. PHP type casting rules can be pretty counter-intuitive

... I would not rely on automatic type juggling. Simply, define a syntax you are comfortable with, cast to string when reading and write your own code to cast to boolean.

```
<?php

function get_bool($value){
    switch( strtolower($value) ){
        case 'true': return true;
        case 'false': return false;
        default: return NULL;
    }
}

$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <empty_tag/>
    <true_tag>true</true_tag>
    <false_tag>false</false_tag>
</data>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
var_dump( get_bool((string)$xml->empty_tag) );
var_dump( get_bool((string)$xml->true_tag) );
var_dump( get_bool((string)$xml->false_tag) );
```

Whatever, if you are curious about how to make `(bool)` work, you are basically dealing with objects so this is the rule that applies when casting to boolean:

- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags: FALSE
- Every other value: TRUE

That means that you will only get `FALSE` with `<investigating />` (and `TRUE` with absolutely anything else). A trick I can think of to widen the range of possible TRUE values is to perform double casting:

```
(bool)(string)$xml->investigating
```

**Update:** don't forget to debug with `var_dump()`. If you use `echo` you'll find that `TRUE` boolean casts to `'1'` string and `FALSE` to `''` (empty string).

Comment: im having issue the sting `false` when casting to boll returns 1 and not 0

Comment: Please keep in mind, that `xsd:boolean` allows `true` and `false` as well as `1` and `0`. So if you import an XML document validating against a XSD schema, you should handle both options correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are not grabbing the right element.

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $statusXml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
    if ($statusXml = simplexml_load_file($filename)) {
        $investigating = (bool) $statusXml->investigating[0];
        echo $investigating;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is quite old but just in case someone is looking for an answer. You could just use:

```
<example is-true=1>
```

or

```
<example is-true=0>
```

This should work fine.

Note using `<example is-true="0">` will return true if you use an an if statement on it.